# SharePoint 2010 Blog URLs

Tags: sharepoint, url-rewriting, sharepoint-2010

I have a blog hosted on SharePoint 2010 with default settings. The URL for my blog posts looks something like http://domainname/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=somenumber

How can I use meaningful names instead of these default URLs? 
Can you please point me to some useful links on how to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, [http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx)
<p>Just for your information

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Community Kit for SharePoint: Enhanced Blog Edition 3.0](http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/28520) solution.
One of its many features is:

> SEO Friendly URL's - blog post URL's
>   that look like
>   /archive/2007/08/25/sharepoint-chart-tool.aspx
>   instead of
>   /Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=37

To see a blog running on SharePoint Foundation 2010 with CKS:EBE 3.0 go [here](http://www.thekickboard.com/archive/2010/07/24/running-cksebe-3-0-on-sharepoint-foundation-2010.aspx).